# Best practice for creating default values in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell, but i am curious what is the best practice for creating default variable in Powershell. This is an [example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730957.aspx), which i am referencing. In case if you just want to initialize default variables, without intention to pass any parameters to function. Which is better way number 1 or 2 or none of them. :)

1.

```
  function test
        {
            param ([int]$x = 5,[int]$y = 14)
             $x * $y 
        }
```

2.

```
   function test
        {
             [int]$x = 5
             [int]$y = 14
             $x * $y 
        }
```

Comment: _"want to initialize default variables, without intention to pass any parameters"_ - this answers itself, as in **#1** you are defining parameters to be passed, which you don't want. So it's **#2**. You can simplify further as PowerShell is a [loosely typed language](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/l/looslang.htm): `$x = 5`.

Comment: @gms0ulman Being loosely typed can also mean sometimes being interpreted as strings and weird behaviors.  Strictly-typing your parameters is a good practice

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 For **parameters**, strongly agree. For regular assignments within a script/function, strongly disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just depends on your use-case. If you truly never intend to change the variables, #2 is correct.

I think you just need to ask yourself what future use-cases might be. Would changing the values break your function? The ability to supply parameters is very useful, if not now, perhaps in the future.

Basically, if you're using the variables as `FINAL`, #2 is fine, but in all other cases I would say #1 is more correct.

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to take parameters to your function, use `Param()`.  By default, undefined values will be `$Null`

```
Function Test
{
Param(
  [Int]
  $X = 5,
  [Int]
  $Y = 14
)
    Return $X * $Y
}
Function Test2
{
    $X=5; $Y=14
    $X * $Y
}
> Test2
>> 70
> Test
>> 70
> Test 5 20
>> 100
```

Comment: My intention is not to pass any parameters to function, what is the case than ?